# very strange raw_input work using ssh connection

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, raw-input

```
#! python2

print 'a'
for i in range(3):
    k = int(raw_input('number? '))
    print k

print k ** 2
```

When I run this code from a remote machine it works like this:

> /prints nothing but awaits/ - /I give him 1/
>   
> /prints nothing but awaits/ - /I give him 2/
>   
> /prints nothing but awaits/ - /I give him 3/
>   
> /prints/ - a
>   
> /prints/ - number? 1
>   
> /prints/ - number? 2
>   
> /prints/ - number? 3
>   
> /prints/ - 9

So it waits for all raw_input commands to be executed and then it runs the whole program (or only prints the whole program which was already executed). If I don't run it remotely it works as expected. Does anyone know why this code behave so strangely?

Comment: Output is most likely getting buffered

Comment: Hi @michal-gigori same as Padraic, no issue for me. I have a VM on AWS and I have no issues